# windows-C exe-files run on DOS not on Windows

Tags: c

exe-file in Windows OS (code written in C) runs only in a DOS-window, not in a window of the Windows OS. Tried 3 compilers with the same result. I wanted to use my C-programs done in linux.

tried code::blocks with three compilers

same problem with any program

as above; so-called windows-C programs run on DOS not on Windows

Comment: Program is defined as DOS program, not Windows program. Has `main`. Needs `WinMain`. Needs also message loop.

Comment: Do you mean the command prompt? If so, you won't be able to make your apps run in a window without fundamentally changing them.

Comment: (1) There is no DOS in any Windows version released in the last 20 years. A Windows console has no relationship with DOS; it is a Windows console. (2) A Windows executable is built either for the console subsystem or for the graphical subsystem. (3) You need to tell your compiler what kind of executable you want. (4) Programs for the graphical subsystem and programs for the console subsystem are very different.